# Software RAID: file system becomes read-only, mdadm fails with SEGFAULT

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, software-raid, mdadm

I have software RAID1 on Ubuntu 10.10 (Linux ubuntu 2.6.35-32-generic-pae). It is dedicated server I control via SSH.

Yesterday datacenter people changed one HDD which was crushed. I did not run rebuild yesterday and now the whole file system becomes read-only, `mdadm` fails with `Segmentation fault` error.

What are the steps to recover the system in that case?

Comment: Simplest?  Dump the RO file system(s) to external media, get the hardware straightened out, reinstall (reinitialising the mirrors), restore.  It may well be possible to recover the machine without that, but it's a more tortuous and less certain route.  Whatever you do, I'd do that backup before anything at all.

Comment: @MadHatter thank you for suggestion, already doing backup